# Storing images on Web Servers

Tags: javascript, c#, html, image, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to understand the proper way of storing images.  I was doing research and looking at how google does it with their google drive and for example, I see something like this:

https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/0B1qZWmK2ucS8UTEteU9YODRhcFU=w32-h32-p-k-nu-iv1

Now that link makes absolutely no sense to me and whatever they did to produce it, I am sure part of it was to hide their folder structure and thus the location of the image.

The other thing is when you visit that link, it becomes this:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/S4P4uR8M79xX-2EQb6LMQRJQnl1F4ZzhRP6PZeGzCFQvBGRF0ch6V7VI_pwGqMQEKktEg8sLeOVYqqiFyj6RgoJVme18cldb2EdVFAM-SuFR4EnaKJ-LmED0hzqe3kD5TCPI9TdPGJWryHwpeXmUV-PdTrdTsNq_0fIO99_Rt-NamjrABTGg-aCTyyHILm5MY0oqcvF85vyr2WX3tq9GvGIUJV1Z6zTQ1G1lSBB0GrZA8jrfmrYsI7mpklwYW4vzviWzLSs29YRaywT4diKtqFssXDmIWnaPI8BR3CvqnwS03WnQs--UFVNxvRcrJpYqmhYOM8I92gU6F8stST2d85Vmt2hOG6doLoR2Vus5QWceNDwztGN4UUR2KS2Nhp859nuEaCwZWG0U6HhjG4L164pHE31qAQsrKknRLo-PtJPwNWf712uVIViHj6EehK7_3OuI6NwnMoLzdNrWPDeHOKtwRgna2xasDAHgeKupAyA0udMUY4KlPg-zSkLXQxniM8858DSdFESL9pImCMaKaloV8HcieLLxywCOZIxm9GLFsPT0E1TybzBhjCdEhRtNgklX8TFv=w32-h32-p-k-nu

I am wondering if there are guides out there that describe the method above or something similar to storing images, I've had no luck with finding guides that follow this methodology.

Comment: If you are making a website you should add a folder called Images and store them in there and your code would be similar to '<img src="Images/something.jpg" alt="description" width="% or px" height="% or px">'

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.  I know how to store images, i am trying to figure out the right way to securing them.